# Why did Kevin Durant switch to the Golden State Warriors?

Tags: basketball, nba

Kevin Durant switched from the Oklahoma City Thunder to the Golden State Warriors for the 2016-17 NBA season. I was wondering why he moved and would really like to know more about it. Why couldn't he just stay on the Thunder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All we can really tell you here is what Durant himself said about the move. Quoting from [this ESPN article](http://www.espn.co.uk/nba/story/_/id/16759826/kevin-durant-announces-sign-golden-state-warriors), Durant said:

> "The primary mandate I had for myself in making this decision was to have it based on the potential for my growth as a player - as that has always steered me in the right direction, but I am also at a point in my life where it is of equal importance to find an opportunity that encourages my evolution as a man: moving out of my comfort zone to a new city and community which offers the greatest potential for my contribution and personal growth. With this in mind, I have decided that I am going to join the Golden State Warriors."

Reading between the lines, I would interpret "my growth as a player" as "chance to win a championship".